# .map is not a fucntion error in React when setting data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am learning react and have below observation .

I am not able to understand the reason behind the error.

I have below code -

**React:**

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log()
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/records/').then((data) => {console.log('server returned ... ',typeof(data));setRecords(data)}
    ).catch( e => console.log(e))
    
},[])

 const [records,setRecords] = useState([]);
```

1. When only `data` is used in side `then clause in axios` , I get below error , `Uncaught TypeError: records.map is not a function`
2. But when I change the code as below - please note `{data}` instead of just `data` , the above error is resolved.

   axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/records/').then(({data}) => {...}

Can anybody please explain the above behaviour ?

I tried to print the `type of variable data` , but in both cases it is coming as `object`

Why above error is gone when `{data}` is used instead of `{data}`

**Express:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
const port = 8000
app.use(cors())


const Records = [
    {
        recordName:'First Record',
        artistName:'First Artist',
        description: 'First Artist Description'
    },
    {
        recordName:'Second Record',
        artistName:'Second Artist',
        description: 'Second Artist Description'
    }

]

app.get('/api/records', (req, res) => {
  res.send(Records)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: It means “data” is a property of the retrieved data.

Comment: the reason is that when the response resolves, axios returns an object that contains a property called data where the data sent by the server lives. Which means that you have to destructor the response and get the data from it, thus the syntax `({data}) => ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set your data as below because in axios we get response in object

```
  const [records,setRecords] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
        console.log()
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/records/').then((resData) => {console.log('server returned ... ',typeof(resData));setRecords(resData.data || [])}
        ).catch( e => console.log(e))
        
   },[])
```